# Equivalent of `log1p` for matrices, aka `logdet_eyep`

Tags: python, math, scientific-computing

Most scientific libraries (e.g. numpy/scipy) provide a numerically stable implementation of `log1p(x) = log(1 + x)` which yields sensible values, even when `x` is so small in magnitude that floating point arithmetic leads to rounding errors for naive implementations.

Is there an equivalent implementation for the log-determinant of matrices to evaluate `log(det(identity + A))`, where `A` is an `n` by `n` matrix, and `identity` is the `n` by `n` identity matrix. For example, if `A = alpha * identity` is a diagonal matrix with `alpha` on the diagonal, the expression becomes `log(det(identity * (1 + alpha)))=n * log1p(alpha)`. However, a general method for evaluating the expression (i.e. arbitrary `A`) evades me.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of size matrices are you dealing with?

Comment: I'm looking at relatively small matrices with `n` generally less than ten or so.

Comment: Would computing the eigenvalues of `A` first be a reasonable approach? If `e_1` through `e_n` are the eigenvalues of `A` (with multiplicity) then `1 + e_1` through `1 + e_n` are the eigenvalues of `identity + A`, so you want `sum_i(log1p(e_i))`, except that some care would be needed to deal with the `e_i` for which `1 + e_i` is not real and positive.

Comment: Nice, for the particular application, my matrices are positive definite so I don't have to worry about the signs of the eigenvalues. However, the following seems to do the trick in general: `logdet = np.log1p(np.where(evals > -1, evals, - evals - 2)).sum()` and `sign = np.prod(np.sign(evals))`.